# Problems trying to work around WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter deprecation using Spring Boot 2.7.5

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-security, boot

When updating spring boot version 2.7.5 I noticed that the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class was deprecated in this version.
I followed the steps as described in section 2.2 on article on [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-deprecated-websecurityconfigureradapter)
to customize my application's authentication rules, but the filterChain method is not even being called during application startup, as with the "configure" function using spring boot version 2.2.3.
Can anyone help me?

Below I show the before and after of my changes.

Before

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
class SecurityConfiguration : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        val tokenTypes: List<TokenType> = mapper.readValue(jsonTokenTypes, Array<TokenType>::class.java).toList()
        http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/graphql").permitAll()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(
                AuthFilter.create(keySet, tokenTypes),
                RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter::class.java
            )
    }
}
```

After

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
class SecurityConfiguration() {

    @Value("\${vehicle.op.jwk.key-set}")
    private lateinit var keySet: List<String>

    @Value("\${vehicle.op.jwt.token-types}")
    private lateinit var jsonTokenTypes: String

    protected val mapper = jacksonObjectMapper()

    @Bean
    fun filterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
        val tokenTypes: List<TokenType> = mapper.readValue(jsonTokenTypes, Array<TokenType>::class.java).toList()
        http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/graphql").permitAll()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(
                AuthFilter.create(keySet, tokenTypes),
                RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter::class.java
            )

        return http.build()


    }
```

Application starts up normally, as shown in the log below:

```
13:22:33: Executing 'bootRun -Dspring.profiles.active=homolog'...

> Task :checkApolloVersions UP-TO-DATE
> Task :generateMainServiceApolloSources NO-SOURCE
> Task :compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :bootRunMainClassName UP-TO-DATE

> Task :bootRun   __  __       _     _ ___________  |  \/  | ___ | |__ (_)___  \ \ \ \  | |\/| |/ _ \| '_ \| |  / / \ \ \ \  | |  | | (_) | |_) | | / /   ) ) ) )  |_|  |_|\___/|_.__/|_|/_/   / / / / 
===========================/_/_/_/  :: my_application :: (vlatest)

2022-12-06 13:22:37.312  INFO 29076 --- [           main] i.company.op.vehicle.VehicleApplicationKt  : Starting VehicleApplicationKt using Java 11.0.16 on DESKTOP-07SSK0A with PID 29076 (C:\company\GitHub\my_application\build\classes\kotlin\main started by admin in C:\company\GitHub\my_application) 2022-12-06 13:22:37.316  INFO 29076 --- [           main] i.company.op.vehicle.VehicleApplicationKt  : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default" 2022-12-06 13:22:37.816  INFO 29076 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode. 2022-12-06 13:22:37.883  INFO 29076
--- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 62 ms. Found 4 JPA repository interfaces. 2022-12-06 13:22:38.065  INFO 29076 --- [       main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=c811da27-aff3-39ab-b4ee-d6bb20987e72 2022-12-06 13:22:38.602  INFO 29076 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 9090 (http) 2022-12-06 13:22:38.611  INFO 29076 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat] 2022-12-06 13:22:38.612  INFO 29076 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.68] 2022-12-06 13:22:38.718  INFO 29076 --- [       main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext 2022-12-06 13:22:38.719  INFO 29076 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1351 ms 2022-12-06 13:22:38.872  INFO 29076 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting... 2022-12-06 13:22:39.037  INFO 29076 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed. 2022-12-06 13:22:39.507  INFO 29076 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SELECT COUNT(*) FROM public.liq_db_changelog_lock 2022-12-06 13:22:39.519  INFO 29076 --- [ main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SELECT COUNT(*) FROM public.liq_db_changelog_lock 2022-12-06 13:22:39.520  INFO 29076 --- [ main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SELECT LOCKED FROM public.liq_db_changelog_lock WHERE ID=1 2022-12-06 13:22:39.533  INFO 29076 --- [           main] l.lockservice.StandardLockService        : Successfully acquired change log lock 2022-12-06 13:22:39.545  INFO 29076 --- [           main] liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog    : Reading resource: db/changelog/202210050955-changelog.sql 2022-12-06 13:22:39.552  INFO 29076 --- [           main] liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog    : Reading resource: db/changelog/202210051005-changelog.sql 2022-12-06 13:22:39.561  INFO 29076 --- [           main] liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog    : Reading resource: db/changelog/202210141724-changelog.sql 2022-12-06 13:22:39.569  INFO 29076 --- [           main] liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog    : Reading resource: db/changelog/202210310837-changelog.sql 2022-12-06 13:22:39.653  INFO 29076 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SELECT MD5SUM FROM public.liq_db_changelog WHERE MD5SUM IS NOT NULL LIMIT 1 2022-12-06 13:22:39.657  INFO 29076 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SELECT COUNT(*) FROM public.liq_db_changelog 2022-12-06 13:22:39.659  INFO 29076 --- [      main] l.c.StandardChangeLogHistoryService      : Reading from public.liq_db_changelog 2022-12-06 13:22:39.659  INFO 29076 --- [      main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SELECT * FROM public.liq_db_changelog ORDER BY DATEEXECUTED ASC, ORDEREXECUTED ASC 2022-12-06 13:22:39.683  INFO 29076 --- [           main] l.lockservice.StandardLockService        : Successfully released change log lock 2022-12-06 13:22:39.831  INFO 29076 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default] 2022-12-06 13:22:39.911  INFO 29076 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.12.Final 2022-12-06 13:22:40.122  INFO 29076 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final} 2022-12-06 13:22:40.242  INFO 29076
--- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect 2022-12-06 13:22:40.651  INFO 29076 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform] 2022-12-06 13:22:40.658  INFO 29076 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default' 2022-12-06 13:22:42.695  INFO 29076 --- [           main] s.b.a.g.s.GraphQlWebMvcAutoConfiguration : GraphQL endpoint HTTP POST /graphql 2022-12-06 13:22:43.217  WARN 29076 --- [           main] .s.s.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration : 

Using generated security password: 6e231318-c400-4c42-bb52-079a429bd04a

This generated password is for development use only. Your security configuration must be updated before running your application in production.

2022-12-06 13:22:43.411  INFO 29076 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@4e92c6c2, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@71a18feb, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@26aecf31, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@693f9ab5, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@197d6cc9, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@286f8e90, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@327fd5c9, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@3d1b6816, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@66032b8d, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@70a9f4b7, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@1abacff3, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@4a3d4cd2, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@7c1a5092, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@3f04847e, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@76e56b17, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@169f4152] 2022-12-06 13:22:43.478  INFO 29076 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 9090 (http) with context path '' 2022-12-06 13:22:43.488  INFO 29076
--- [           main] i.company.op.vehicle.VehicleApplicationKt  : Started VehicleApplicationKt in 6.557 seconds (JVM running for 6.906)
```

Originally my application validates only the Bearer Token given in the request header, and after upgrade spring boot version now it requires a user/password authentication.

Comment: *"filterChain method is not even being called during application startup"* - Application starts successfully, without exception, do you see a list of filters on the console? *"Customization of authentication rules do not work"* - how did you check that (i.e. which path you've call, what was the response) ?

Comment: Voted to close lack of debugging logs etc

Comment: Logs was added in the original post @AlexanderIvanchenko

Comment: OK, what about clarifying *"Customization of authentication rules do not work"* ? It's not a helpful problem description.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko Originally my application validates only the Bearer Token given in the request header, and after upgrade spring boot version now it requires a user/password authentication.

Comment: You need to implement any UserDetailsManager. The default password is auto-generated for username: "user". For example and you can create an empty InMemoryUserDetailsManager @Bean but it has no sense :D . 
Also in spring-boot 3.0.0 / security 6 .antMatchers is deprecated.